# Keep history of Excel column entries as suggestions for new values

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I enter values in a column, the values already there are given as a suggestion for new entry, if they match the start of the string.

There is a script that regularly deletes values from the file, it is done when the workbook is closed.

Is there any way to keep all the historical values from a column as possible suggestions?

So values that are not right now in the column, but were before.

Comment: yes, but it will require VBA

Comment: @gns100 OK, I haven't used VBA that much, but I could give a crack.

Comment: I might used Python library xlwings though as I more familiar with that. Also I have all the historical values I want as suggestions in another .csv and in a SQLite database if that helps.

Comment: I would probably instantiate the historical value list with excel's data validation. I'm guessing you can use python and/or the "deletion" script to get/update that list into excel. Then maybe you won't have to do any VBA...

Comment: I would want them to have the option to insert some new value, does the data validation allow this?

Comment: yes, to allow other values, go to the error alert tab and unselect the error message. The only problem I see is that you need some workaround if you want the history/list to be updated in real time. good luck.